# NGINX epoll_ctl(1, 7) failed (17: File exists)

Tags: nginx, quic, http3

It only happens when I add:

```
location / {
proxy_pass https://backend-server.local:443;
}
```

The logs say:

```
2021/06/14 18:48:56 [alert] 700448#0: *2 epoll_ctl(1, 7) failed (17: File exists), client: 1.2.3.4, server: backend-server.local, request: "POST / HTTP/3", host: "backend-server.local"
```

I have compiled with `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --build=quiche-7eb57c4 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_v3_module --with-openssl=../quiche/deps/boringssl --with-quiche=../quiche --with-debug`, and this only happens when a request body is sent with the request. How can I resolve this?

I have built with the latest version of nginx in github, and latest version of quiche from github.

This seems to go away when `proxy_store on` is added in nginx.conf, but it starts showing errors like

```
2021/06/20 18:12:01 [crit] 12151#0: *1 mkdir() "/usr/local/nginx/html/assets/ttf" failed (2: No such file or directory) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /assets/ttf/Example/Example-Regular.ttf HTTP/3", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/assets/ttf/Example/Example-Regular.ttf", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Can someone please create the tag [quiche] for me? It is pretty relevant to this question.

Comment: im facing this issue aswell, although its happening for all php requests.